# ST AN5457 - What is "m"?

Tags: rf, st

I'm reading [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5457-rf-matching-network-design-guide-for-stm32wl-series-stmicroelectronics.pdf) application note. What does the formula on page 22 mean?

[image]

Is this the adjustment factor and how do I get this formula?

Answer (score 0):

> *how do I get this formula*

It's a rather convoluted way of dealing with an L-pad impedance transformer formed by L1 and C1 (in a light blue box that I added) shown here from your link: -

[image]

So, L1 has to do two things: -

- Provide enough inductance to cancel the capacitance in your device (the dark blue box)
- provide more inductance to transform 15.27 Ω to 50 Ω when used with capacitor C1

Then it's down to looking into impedance transformer theory for an L-pad.

Here it is from [my basic website](http://stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html): -

[image]

Using the calculator on my page, the part of L1 that does the impedance conversion is 4.223 nH but, it needs to be a tad more to cancel the 144 pF in the output impedance. The extra part is a value of 0.233 nH bringing the full value of L1 to 4.446 nH.

If you look on page 23 of your document, they calculate a value for L1 of 4.45 nH.

The next page they take you through some more math to find C1. My website calculator gives a figure of 5.5305 pF and, they also get the same value (5.53 pF)

So, it's up to you; either try to follow this convoluted explanation or use the derivation for L and C on my website. But if you insist on this: -

> *What is "m"?*

I have to point you at the formula for capacitance in the 2nd picture. Based on this (and knowing that RL is 50 Ω), \$m = 50\times\omega C_1\$.